# fastlane match integration with Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops, devops, fastlane

We are using Azure DevOps of build our ios application, So we are using xcode to build to application and now we want to sign the application to deploy it to app centre or test flight so that we have a problem that we saved our certifacates in secure files folder but when for every month our certificates are getting expired and pipelines signing part is getting failed untill unless we upload the updated files to the secure files section so the thing is for every month the certs are getting out of sync with apple account.

so in our local environment we are using fastlane with match to auto renewal the certs and build the code and sigin so we want to integrate the fastlane with azure devops but didn't find any useful article can some please help me on this.

or else any workaround to mitigate this make the azure pipelines in sync with apple account without manually uploading the certs to secure files.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fastlane match integration with Azure DevOps pipelines

There is an extension [Apple App Store](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.app-store), which install and use fastlane tools or we could find [instructions on installing fastlane through a package manager](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/).

After installing the fastlane tools, we could use the fastlane’s match action to manage your iOS certificates.

You could check this document [Continuous integration and delivery with Team Services and App Center](https://www.theta.co.nz/news-blogs/tech-blog/continuous-integration-and-delivery-with-team-services-and-app-center/) for some more details.

Besides, regarding of manually updating in secure files section, we have the Rest API to add the secure files:

```
POST
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles?api-version=5.0-preview.1&name={fileName}
```

So we could upload the local certificates to the secure files programmatically. Please refer to [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9172#issuecomment-626474029) for the Powershell script example to use the Rest API.

Comment: you can use fastlane match. Follow the documentation to store your certs in a private Github repo, and then add a ssh key as a Deploy key.